# Azure Application is not redeploying. Can see .scm extension for azure appservice URL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a sample .war application onto my azure app service using external GIT. I then disconnected external git and the redeployed another .war app using azure CLI.

> az webapp deploy --resource-group name --name appname --src-path My_App.war --target-path My_App.war --restart true --type war

It executed and shows me the URL as

> https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest.
> It is adding scm in the URL. How can I deploy my .war app onto original app service URL without scm?
> My app service url is sill showing the previously deployed app even though I disconnected external git.

Answer (score 0):

**You can deploy your spring boot war application using Maven commands through CLI.**

1. Configure App Service for your application using maven-plugin.

```java
mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.5.0:config
```

[image]

- Choose OS, App Name, Java version, App Service plan while configuring the App Service to deploy the application.

2. Deploy the War file to App Service of your spring boot application.

```java
mvn package azure-webapp:deploy
```

[image]

It will package and process the WAR files and deploy it to Azure App Service and its URL will be `https://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net`:

[image]

**Response:**
Click on the URL to run deployed application.
[image]

> https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest. It is adding scm in the URL

This is [KUDU site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu), where your deployed application related files will be available after deployment.

To run your deployed application, go to **Overview** of your **App Service** and click on the *Default Domain URL*:

[image]